# Have to write full path when checking background image javascript

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

```
if ($("#canvas").css('background-image') == 'url(images/endOfGame.jpg)') {
```

does not work. But this does:

```
var element = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
                var imagex = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');
                console.log(imagex);
                if (imagex === "url(file:///C:/Users/Jack/Documents/myGames/Pong/images/endOfGame.jpg)") {
```

and this does not:

```
var element = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
                    var imagex = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');
                    console.log(imagex);
                    if (imagex === "url(images/endOfGame.jpg)") {
```

why? I have to change the full file path code for every computer i run my game on. Not good.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `if (imagex === "images/endOfGame.jpg") {`

Comment: Can you not just work with a relative path?

Comment: Can we see your directory structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `indexOf` which returns the character position of the found text (0 and above) or -1 if not found:

```
if (imagex.indexOf("url(images/endOfGame.jpg)") >= 0) {
    // yes, string contains that text
}
```

I would prefer:

```
if (imagex.indexOf("images/endOfGame.jpg") >= 0) {
    // yes, string contains that text
}
```

ignoring `url(..)`. The following version ignores differences in case (upper or lower):

```
if (imagex.toUpperCase().indexOf("images/endOfGame.jpg".toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
    // yes, string contains that text
}
```

Comment: I was about to get the last 5 letters of the url result and chuck them in a variable which would also work. The thing is, inside the if statement, i'm going to change the image to "endOfGame1.jpg". So i would have to alter your approach slightly as that also contains the same string (+ the number 1)

Comment: You can use `substring(from, to)` to extract part of a string. Omit the `to` argument to get all of the text after the `from` position. You can use `indexOf('Game')` to get the position where Game starts in the string.

Comment: It's not letting me edit my comment. Thank you i think i will use this approach. I would just have to count the character position and be more specific than >= 0 because of the reason stated in my above comment. Thanks

Comment: Good luck with your game :)

Comment: yes thank you, both ways will work fine. I hadn't thought of them when i asked the question but soon after i thought of the substring way. No difference which one i use really

Comment: Thanks Andy. my reply to person "@" thing isn't working today